# improve Jquery Mobile's slider performance

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile 1.3.2 for my Phonegap Build app. I would like to improve the performance of the slider input : because when you try to slide it on a phone, it is very slow, as I do a lot of UI manipulations after the slider is moved.
Particularly I need to update the value displayed on the slider track ($("#cursortext")) the quickest possible.

Also, is it possible to make everything that is `$(document).on("slidestop","#levelrange", function () {` asynchronous so that if the user can change the slider while this executes if needed.

Can you help me achive that ?

Here's what I've comme up for now:

HTML:

```
<input id="levelrange" data-theme="a" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" name="userlevel" />
```

JS:

```
$("div.ui-slider div.ui-slider-track .ui-btn-text").attr('id', 'cursortext'); //for speed, see below
    $(document).on("change","#levelrange", function () {
        var newValue = parseInt($('#levelrange').val());
        $("#cursortext").text(newValue); //displays the range value on the slider
        $(document).on("slidestop","#levelrange", function () {
            setLevelText(newValue);
            setTimeout(function() { //do the long thing afterwards  
    console.log('avant resetListsModelsOn funfeatureOn '+funfeatureOn);         
                resetListsModelsOn(prodata, funfeatureOn,0);
                //add images to selects
                addProImagesInSelect();
                addBrandImagesInSelect();
                clearInterval(animationFactor);
                $("#blink").removeClass('active');
                clearInterval(animationWeight);
                $("#weightdata .ui-block-a").removeClass('active');
                $("#weightdata #number1").removeClass('active');
                $("#number2").removeClass('active');
                localStorage.setItem("userLevel", newValue.toString());
            }, 9);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I also use sliders for the same thing, but I'm using jQM 1.4.0 and its fine and not slow. In fact everything is smoother and faster on phones with it.

Is there any reason why you're using an older version of jQM?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am using 1.3.2 just because the migration to 1.4 seems complicated, I that involves a lot of testing afterwards.